# Please explain Shemot 23:26

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mishpatim

My loose translation of Shemot 23:26 (feel free to edit, please):

> "There shall not be a miscarriage (I'm somewhat extending Rashi's
>   translation, here) or a barren in your land. I will fill the count of
>   your days."

I can understand the explanation of the end of the verse - "filling the days" as it applies to a miscarriage. In other words, it seems to imply that G-d will avoid having either miscarriages or premature births.

But my understanding of the word עקרה means a woman who has no children, i.e., she cannot give birth. We see this term applied to Sarah, Rivkah and Channa, as examples.

If a woman can't give birth, she has no days when she is preganant. So what does it mean to see I will "fill (complete) the count of your days"?

Answer (score 2):

Rav Hirsch says that it means there will be no premature deaths from any cause. He treats verses 25 and 26 as a unit.

> The natural illnesses and weaknesses which, under the regime of
>   Nature, are considered indispensable from human life, will, under the
>   regime of My Torah, not manifest themselves in your lives. Illness,
>   childlessness and early deaths will be unknown in your land. Not only
>   the land, the inhabitants themselves will be blessed.

*Sforno* is cited in the Art Scroll as having said

> When people live out their days, society will be improved, because
>   they will live long enough to pass on their wisdom and experience to
>   grandchildren.

Thus this is more than just a long life, but a long life that is *full* and meaningful.

[Mishpatim 23:26](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/23.26#e0n6) Ibn Ezra states that not only will everyone live a long and meaningful life, but will have children and grandchildren to rear and teach. People will not outlive their children but will die at the proper age.

> את מספר ימיך אמלא – טעמו: שהשם נתן כח לכל גוף וכמה יעמוד, ואם הוא דבק
>   בשם אשר לו נתכנו עלילות, יסבב סבות לשמור כח הגוף,א ויחזק הרוח המכלכל.
>   והפך זה ברחקו ממקור החיים, וכן: יראת י״י תוסיף ימים ושנות רשעים תקצרנה
>   (משלי י׳:כ״ז). ואם השם ידע בטרם היות הנער כל אשר יבחר, אין דעת השם
>   מסבבת לאדם שיבחר ברע ויעזוב הטוב, אחר שנתן בידו ממשלת ויכולת.
>
> אביהם. ומלת עקרה – כוללת אשת איש ובהמתו. והרביעית: שגם הוא יחיה שנים
>   רבות. והנה ידענו, כי כל איש יש לו קצב וזמן ידוע שיכול לחיות, כפי רוב
>   החום וליחה התולדת, לא אש זרה ולחה נכריה, כי היא הפך התולדת. והדבק בשם
>   יחזק החום והלחהא בכח הנשמה, אז יחיה האדם יותר מהזמן הקצוב. וכן כתוב:
>   יראת י״י תוסיף ימים ושנות רשעים תקצרנה (משלי י׳:כ״ז), וכתוב: בחצי ימיו
>   יעזבנו (ירמיהו י״ז:י״א), וכתוב: כי אם י״י יגפנו או יומו יבא (שמואל א
>   כ״ו:י׳). והנה המת במגפה או מת במלחמה, לא מת ביומו בזמן הקצוב, כפי
>   תולדת החום והלח, כי מחוץ באו לו מקרים. והנה הוא יצילנו מכולם. ובתורה:
>   פן ימות במלחמה (דברים כ׳:ה׳). ואמר שלמה: למה תמות בלא עתך (קהלת
>   ז׳:י״ז). ואין זה הפך חכמת המזלות, כי דברי המזל תלוי בדברים רבים, כאשר
>   אפרש (ראב״ע שמות פירוש שני ל״ג:כ״א) בפסוק ונפלינו אני ועמך (שמות
>   ל״ג:ט״ז). על כן: הנני יוסיף על ימיך (ישעיהו ל״ח:ה׳). ומה אוסיף עוד להאריך.

בכור שור, חזקוני, and רב אברהם בן הרמבם sat that this means that tzadikim will live to a full extended life span while the lifespan of reshaim will be cut short.

> אתא מספר ימיך אמלא – שתהיה זקן ומלא ימים, ולא תמות בלא עתך. כי הרשעים
>   מתים בלא עתם, כדכתיב: ושנות רשעים תקצורנה (משלי י׳:כ״ז).